# Determining the scope of LINQ statement with a using around the DB context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, c#-7.0

I have a function that returns a query result for further filtering like this:

```
public IQueryable<MyData> Query(string name) {
  using (var dbc = new MyDbContext()) 
    return dbc.MyData.Where(v => v.Name == name);
}
```

and then I call it in another function:

```
public f() { 
  var res = Query("john").Select(v => ......
  var resList = res.ToList();
  ...
}
```

What is the scope of `MyDbContext` in this case ? when does it dispose ? when `Query()` returns or when `ToList()` in `f()` finishes ?

If the former, how can I change this so that the DB context is disposed when `ToList()` finishes ?

(Note: I know in general there is usually no need to have using around DbContext in EF but I want it in this case as I'm trying to solve sqlite locking issues)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `using` clause is just a `try finally` block. So `Query` will be converted to something like:

```
public IQueryable<MyData> Query(string name) {
  MyDbContext dbc;

  dbc = new MyDbContext();
  try
  {

     return dbc.MyData.Where(v => v.Name == name);
  }
  finally
  {
     dbc.Dispose();
  }   
}
```

After `Query` returns `IQueryable` the context will most likely be disposed right away (even before the call to `.Select(v => ......` is made).

It's somewhat 'cleaner' to let the caller dispose the context instead. You could create a context object outside of `Query` function and pass it as parameter:

```
public IQueryable<MyData> Query(MyDbContext dbc, string name) {
     return dbc.MyData.Where(v => v.Name == name);
}

public f() { 
  using(var dbc = new MyDbContext())
  {
      var res = Query(dbc, "john").Select(v => ......
      var resList = res.ToList();
      ...
  }      
}
```

The general idea is simple and it's advisable not to over-complicate things:

1. Create dbcontext
2. Do whatever you need to do with it
3. Dispose it